# Get one dimensionial array from a mutlidimensional array in c#

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I have a two dimensional array like this:

```
decimal[,] dataArray;
dataArray = new decimal[10, 20];
```

How can I get an onedimesional array that contains the values from one particular column?

Thanks.

Comment: Show us what have you done until now.

Answer (score 3):

There is no built-in API for slicing multidimensional arrays. Write a loop that goes through all rows, and harvests a specific column into a result array, or use LINQ to "fold" the loop:

```
var col = Enumerable.Range(0, 20).Select(r=>dataArray[3, r]).ToArray();
```

Comment: @MatthewWatson Thanks!